# Although I have the file open in the same folder as my code, it wont execute

Tags: python

A small disclaimer for all, this is my first language for programming and I am still getting used to it, so any suggestions are recommended.

The problem that was given is as follows:

Scraping Numbers from HTML using BeautifulSoup In this assignment you will write a Python program similar to http://www.py4e.com/code3/urllink2.py. The program will use urllib to read the HTML from the data files below, and parse the data, extracting numbers and compute the sum of the numbers in the file.

We provide two files for this assignment. One is a sample file where we give you the sum for your testing and the other is the actual data you need to process for the assignment.

Sample data: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html (Sum=2553)
Actual data: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_97465.html (Sum ends with 19)
You do not need to save these files to your folder since your program will read the data directly from the URL. Note: Each student will have a distinct data url for the assignment - so only use your own data url for analysis.
Data Format
The file is a table of names and comment counts. You can ignore most of the data in the file except for lines like the following:

```
<tr><td>Modu</td><td><span class="comments">90</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Kenzie</td><td><span class="comments">88</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Hubert</td><td><span class="comments">87</span></td></tr>
```

You are to find all the  tags in the file and pull out the numbers from the tag and sum the numbers.
Look at the sample code provided. It shows how to find all of a certain kind of tag, loop through the tags and extract the various aspects of the tags.
...

```
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
   # Look at the parts of a tag
   print 'TAG:',tag
   print 'URL:',tag.get('href', None)
   print 'Contents:',tag.contents[0]
   print 'Attrs:',tag.attrs
```

You need to adjust this code to look for span tags and pull out the text content of the span tag, convert them to integers and add them up to complete the assignment.

I have written this:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib.urlopen(input("Enter URL: "))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

spans = soup('span')

numbers = []

for span in spans:
    numbers.append(int(span.string))

print (sum(numbers))
```

The error message is that bs4 is not a module even though it is and it is not asking me for the url and not giving me output. I have no clue on how to solve it.

Comment: Also, I have downloaded bs4 and saved it into the same file as my code.

Comment: are you running the script from `cmd.exe`? If so, you still need to "install" `bs4` into your python environment (downloading it isn't enough). In `cmd` run `pip install bs4` then try running the script again.

Comment: you should install beautifulsoup(bs4) using `pip install bs4` ...

Comment: @davedwards, I am running this on visual studios and I am clicking the debugging button.

Comment: @mehai, I think you need to install `bs4` into Visual Studio's Python environment, see here: [How to add a package to python in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652779/1248974)

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx= ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter -')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

numbers = []

spans =  soup('span')
for span in spans:
    numbers.append(int(span.string))

print (sum(numbers))
```

Use this code, works for me.

Comment: What does this have to do with the issue that OP was encountering?