# How do I properly import pygame in Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019?

Tags: python, pygame

I used the unofficial .whl file downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame to install the pygame package and then import in on my Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, but apparently pygame still cannot be found in the list of libraries allowed to be imported in VS Enterprise 2019. How do I properly import and use pygame in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019?

```
#space invaders
#set up the screen
#python 2.7

import turtle
import pygame, sys
import os
pygame.init()

#set up the screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Space Invaders")

#draw border
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("White")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600) #fd == forward
    border_pen.lt(90) #lt == left; takes in degrees as argument
border_pen.hideturtle() #hideturtle() == ht()

#create player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)
playerSpeed = 15

#function for moving the player left and right
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerSpeed
    if (x < -280):
        x = -280
    player.setx(x)
def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerSpeed
    if (x > 280):
        x = 280
    player.setx(x)

#function for binding keys to specific functions
while running:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            running == False
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        move_left()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        move_right()
turtle.listen()
#turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
#turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")

delay = input("Press enter to close")
```

Comment: Is your code relevant here? What we really need is more information on your environment, how you installed the library, etc. Also, are you using Python 2?

Comment: I installed the latest 64bit pygame .whl file using the command prompt of windows. My operating system is Windows 10 and My Visual Studio Enterprise has all the Python extensions installed. Even though I ran the installation command successfully in the cmd, I am not sure whether the pygame library itself was installed properly in Visual Studio

Comment: I am using python 3.7, but I am still checking for deprecated codes from my 2.7 program so that I don't use anything obsolete.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652779/7675174) details installing packages in Visual Studio.